# As of 2022 August, how many times have Solana actually went down?

Tags: solana-program

Solana is known for going down alot in the past 2 years. How many times did it go down and what were the reasons and have they been solved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a relevant question for the stack exchange

Comment: I actually kinda disagree. I'd argue it would be relevant. There's a lot of misinformation regarding how many times Solana has been down as well as a number of new features that have been introduced to prevent it from happening in the future. I think a solid answer to this question would overall be beneficial to the community.

Comment: @C.OG i agree with Sammy .. its good to clear the air with exactly what happened and how it would be mitigated in the future.